# How to use Octave app on macOS Mojave

Tags: macos, terminal

I downloaded the Octave app bundle from [here](http://octave-app.org/). The app is in /⁨Applications⁩. I have been unable to open it from the terminal. I tried the command 'octave' and some other variations from the documentation.

My goal is to be able to run a file `/⁨Users/[me]/Documents⁩/OctavePrograms/firstlast.m`⁩ in the command line by typing `octave firstlast.m` or some variation of it. I would like to understand why I have been unable to run my program.

Comment: Try `open -a "Octave" ~/Documents⁩/OctavePrograms/firstlast.m`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following to open Octave with a file:

```
open -a "Octave" /path/to/file
```

If you want, alias this to `octave` by adding this line to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
alias octave="open -a \"Octave\""
```

Now you should be able to use `octave /path/to/file` anywhere.